# Viewing added places in google places api with codeigniter using biostall map v3 library

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-places-api

First i added some places in the Google places API with the following code snippet..

```
<?php
class PlaceAdd Extends CI_controller{
    public function index(){
        $this->load->model('placeAdd_model');
        $a = $this->placeAdd_model->getAtm();

        foreach($a as $k){

        $jsonpost = '{
                  "location": {
                    "lat": '.$k['Latitude'].',
                    "lng": '.$k['Longitude'].'
                  },
                  "accuracy": 50,
                  "name": "'.$k['ATMName'].'",
                  "phone_number": "'.$k['PriorityMobile'].'",
                  "address": "'.$k['AddressLine1'].'",
                  "types": ["atm"],
                  "website": "http://www.google.com.bd/",
                  "language": "en"
                }';

       $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?key={my api key}";

      $results = $this->ProcessCurl ($url, $jsonpost);
      $data = json_decode($results);
      print_r($data);
    }
  }
}
```

the function

```
ProcessCurl()
```

is written below the code snippet and the data is added because I have received a status: "OK" after the data is added and I also can view the information of the added data by hitting the following URL

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=my_api_key&location=23.790960,90.404426&radius=50&types=atm&name=Banani

consider a scenario that I have 100 ATM information in my database and I have added all the ATM information to Google's database and all the data are under my API key.

Now I want to view all the data(100 ATM info) that I have added under my API key at a time.

And I have tried the CodeIgniter Google Maps V3 API Library

http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library

what I did is:

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class ViewPlaces extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('Googlemaps');
}

public function index(){
    $config['center'] = '23.790960, 90.404426';
    $config['zoom'] = 'auto';
    $config['places'] = TRUE;
    $config['placesLocation'] = '23.790960, 90.404426';
    $config['placesRadius'] = 50; 
    $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);
    $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
    $this->load->view('map_view', $data);
  }
}
```

here in the "Googlemaps" library I have added my API key but in the map it isn't showing the places which I have added.

Or is there any other way of doing that i.e. I want to view all the 100 ATMs in  a map that means the places which are under my API key and I want to view them in a map.

Comment: did you mention your API key in biostall ?

Comment: yes I have inserted my API key in the "Googlemaps" library @MurtazaHussain

Comment: https://github.com/BIOSTALL/CodeIgniter-Google-Maps-V3-API-Library/blob/master/application/libraries/Googlemaps.php

here is the raw library file and in the library there is a line (line # 23)

`var $apiKey = '{my api key}'; // If you've got an API key you can use it by passing this parameter. Setup an API key here: https://code.google.com/apis/console`

there I have put my API key

Comment: expecting some help from you .... can you ?? @MurtazaHussain